# Ubuntu Jaunty + sendmail + PHP + mail() Premission Errors

Tags: apache-2.2, php, permissions, sendmail

I'm having issues trying to get PHP's `mail` function to work on my Ubuntu 9.04 VPS with sendmail and Apache (and other less relevant stuff, of course).

From PHP I receive no error, save a return value of `false` from the `mail` function.

The last error in `/var/log/mail.err` is

```
sendmail[14837]: NOQUEUE: SYSERR(www-data): can not chdir(/var/spool/mqueue-client/): Permission denied
```

Now, I appreciate that this is saying `www-data` (the user Apache is running as) does not have read access on some required directory (`/var/spool/mqueue-client`).

So, knowing that (and for test purposes only), I ran `chmod 777 /var/spool/mqueue-client` and reran the script, which this time succeeded (hurray), however `/var/log/mail.err` now says

```
sendmail[14874]: dangerous permissions=42777 on queue directory /var/spool/mqueue-client/
```

So I'm wondering how I can configure things so my script can run using non-dangerous permissions.

Comment: First advice: Switch to Postfix. Second: Who is owner:group of /var/spool/mqueue-client? What were the permissions before switching to 777? Why are you still using Ubuntu 9.04 and not 10.04 LTS?

Comment: I can't switch to postfix as `apt` no longer works on Jaunty.  Owner/group of `mqueue-client` are both `smmsp`.  I'm not certain what the permissions were before I switched them (rookie error), however setting `770` reverts it to the old `chdir` related error.  Long story short on LTS is that my VPS provider does not make it easy to dist-upgrade.  I will probably upgrade nearer the end of thos month by creating a new VPS and cancelling the old one.

Comment: Which sendmail version are you running? `ls -l $(which sendmail)`? `groups smmsp`?

Comment: `8.14.3` / `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 Oct  4 12:05 /usr/sbin/sendmail -> /etc/alternatives/sendmail` / `smmsp sasl`

Answer (score 1):

You could try to chmod 775 the /var/spool/mqueue-client and then add www-data to the smmsp group. I agree though if you can switch to postfix somehow, you would be much better off.

Comment: That still gives me the permissions error, and also `sendmail[15164]: NOQUEUE: SYSERR(www-data): can not write to queue directory /var/spool/mqueue-client/ (RunAsGid=33, required=114): Permission denied`

Comment: Ooh, you may need to restart apache, (not reload)

Comment: It looks like the appropiate permissions are 770: `drwxrwx--- smmsp  smmsp ... /var/spool/mqueue-client` And with www-data added to /etc/group it should have access to read/write, however this is work around and still may be a security issue.

Comment: With `drwxrws---  smmsp smmsp ... mqueue-client` and `www-data` in the `smmsp` group (`useradd: user www-data exists`), after restarting Apache I now get `sendmail[15984]: NOQUEUE: SYSERR(www-data): can not chdir(/var/spool/mqueue-client/): Permission denied`.  It seems that, for some reason, it's not seeing that `www-data` is in the `smmsp` group.

Comment: Also: `www-data` has id `33` in `/etc/groups`, and user `smmsp` has id `114`.

Comment: I seems that `www-data` did not get added to the `smmsp` group. Try: `useradd -G smmsp www-data` as root. Then be sure to restart apache.

Comment: Restarting apache should not affect the interpretation of the permissions. It looks like minty is confused about group and user identifiers. useradd -G smmsp www-data should be sufficient

Comment: @symcbean: That's what I did (I now get the response `useradd: user www-data exists`), however `groups smmsp` only shows `smmsp sasl`.

Comment: The line in your `/etc/group` should look something like this: `smmsp:x:114:smmsp,www-data` The appropriate command to test would be `groups www-data`

Comment: Sorry - should be usermod -a -G smmsp www-data

Comment: Sendmail-8.12+ Should be installed as set group id. Adding www-data to smmsp group should not be necessary in standard configurations.